# ReactJS: Is it possible to change my 'data-target' attribute dynamically? rather then individually setting them?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, react-bootstrap

Basically I'm creating a bootstrap table in my react project and am using an accordion toggle to contain the excess info in a dropdown. As of now when i click the dropdown all of the dropdowns open, so i'm trying to set the data-target attribute (currently set to `#demo1`) and the id attribute to change dynamically in order to give me better control over which drop down is open and when.

I'm using React and bootstrap and am still fairly new :S

I tried setting data-target to a unique ID `{item._id}` which is the same as the key, but nothing happens i presume it's because i don't have the # in front of it, but it would error out if i add it to the front of the expression.

```
<tr
  key={item._id}
  className="accordion-toggle"
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#demo1"
>
    {...}
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colSpan="6" className="hiddenRow">
    <div className="accordion-body collapse" id="demo1">
      <table className="table table-dark">    
      </table>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this by tracking the state of all Dropdowns (open vs closed) in the parent component in an array, and passing it to the child component as a boolean prop such as 'isOpen'.

If there is more to it, perhaps you can attach a screenshot of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

May not work with older versions of react/bootstrap, but with bootstrap 5 & react 18 (possibly down to 16) you can wrap the attribute in curly braces and concatenate your desired id, e.g. {"#demo" + idx}.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).